# How can I select all the text that appears before a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, select

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="Select this text http://www.domain.com" />
```

**JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var value = $('#field').val();

    //select text
});
```

How can I select all the `text` that appears before a `url`? Everything after the url (including the url itself) should not be selected.

BTW, the text may also contain numbers and special characters.

**Solution:**
I ended up using Rocket's solution `split(/\shttps?:\/\//)` (see below).

Comment: Will the url always start with HTTP?

Comment: Yes :) Well, either http or https.

Comment: Will there be anything after the URL?

Comment: There might be text after the URL as well, but only the text before the URL should be selected. If that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url will always be of the hypertext protocol, then you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myText = $('#field').val().split(' http')[0];
});
```

This will capture both http and https protocols, and is the least computing-intensive approach as far as I can tell.

Comment: +1, this seems like the best way (unless the text contained ' http' :-P).

Comment: Good point Rocket. If this was the case then you could just find the last instance of ' http' in the sequence and then take the substring up to that index. Didn't even think of that.

Comment: You could also use a regex: `split(/\shttps?:\/\//)`.  This will look for ' http://' or ' https://'

Answer (score 0):

The text is just a string. You need to identify what makes the URL part of it unique - starting http:// ( making sure it is not https:// ), including www., or whatever. Once you have identified what matches the url and not the other characters before this, then it is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the java objec Regexp.  This will allow you to use pattern matching and select the text based on the url pattern.

here is a tutorial on javascript RegExp object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

and this is a good javascript RegExp tester:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Let me know if you have any troubles with the regexp!!